# SQL Query performance (break-up one query into smaller ones or not)

Tags: sql, performance, teradata, database-performance

I have a SQL query (run on a Teradata platform) which features 
1) an inner join
2) where clause 
3) group by

It takes about 40 minutes to run and I want to make it faster. (I don't have privileges to create an INDEX for this table). The code is below. Should I create an intermediate table W using just the WHERE clause and another intermediate table to filter out the rows of W that intersect with table X and then finally do an inner join ?

```
    create table ABC as
    (select 
        b.acct_nb,
        max(b.lst_pmt) as pmt       
     from
     Y as b inner join X as a on 
     a.acct_nb = b.acct_nb
     where b.amount > 0
     group by b.acct_nb
     );
```

Proposed code:

```
    create table W as
    select acct_nb,amount
    from Y
    where amount > 0;

    create table W2 as
    select a.acct_nb,b.amount
    from X as a inner join W as b
    on a.acct_nb = b.acct_nb;


    create table ABC as
    select a.acct_nb,max(b.lst_pmt) as pmt
    from W2 as a inner join Y as b
    on a.acct_nb = b.acct_nb
    group by b.acct_nb;
```

quit;

Comment: Your `Create Table as Select` is not valid syntax. What are the row counts for both tables and locical Primary & Foreign Keys? Is `acct_nb` in one of those tables unique? Can you share Explain?

Comment: This is the syntax that has been handed to me in the existing code. I'm not a data scientist, but these queries take ~1 hour to run. I don't have the privilege to run EXPLAIN on this particular Table - its a table that can't be modified at all, I believe. I am accessing SQL through SAS's PROC SQL and the database is Teradata.

Comment: As for the number of rows: about 7.9 million in X, and unknown and much much more in Y, since that is a database that contains mane decades' information. Primary Key is acct_nb. I don't have privileges to run EXPLAIN either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proposed code will probably not improve performance.

Whithout Explain or QueryLog info it's hard to advice, but you might try to aggregate before the join:

```
select b.*
from 
 (
   select 
      acct_nb,
      max(lst_pmt) as pmt       
   from Y
   where amount > 0
   group by b.acct_nb
 ) as b 
inner join X as a 
on a.acct_nb = b.acct_nb
```

Comment: I think this is probably the answer... my proposed code when I ran it on SAS to access Teradata gave me an error: : Insufficient Space" or something like that. So breaking up into smaller queries the way I did is the way to go. I tried running this version, and I think it ran, but my system crashed soon afterwards. One bit of info I should've added earlier: X has 7.9 mill rows but Y has 284  mill rows.

Answer (score 0):

This is your query:

```
create table ABC as
    select b.acct_nb, max(b.lst_pmt) as pmt       
    from Y b inner join
         X a 
         on a.acct_nb = b.acct_nb
    where b.amount > 0
    group by b.acct_nb;
```

You are not really using `X` (except for filtering), so I wonder if this does what you want:

```
create table ABC as
    select b.acct_nb, max(b.lst_pmt) as pmt       
    from Y b 
    where b.amount > 0
    group by b.acct_nb;
```

If not, you can use `exists` instead:

```
create table ABC as
    select b.acct_nb, max(b.lst_pmt) as pmt       
    from Y b 
    where b.amount > 0
          exists (select 1 from X a where a.acct_nb = b.acct_nb)
    group by b.acct_nb;
```

I would try these methods before using a temporary table.

Comment: If I were to go with Option 2, I would still need to filter out rows not in X.Would that not make it slower overall? I would have to add an inner join between tables ABC and X on the key variable acct_nb? I will try this and post tomorrow....